The other quarks also have some different properties or strange is the only one?
Particles that contain a strange quark decay more slowly, because of what we see in this answer. The other quarks, besides up and down, also have some particularity? E.g. according to Brumfiel, Geoff (1 March 2001). "The Incredible Shrinking Nucleus" lambda baryon has already been observed in hypernuclei; in this scenario, "the lambda slides into the center of the nucleus and binds the nucleus more tightly together due to its interaction via the strong force. In a lithium isotope (7ΛLi), it made the nucleus 19% smaller."
The journal said that "Millener believes that gamma ray experiments like this will eventually allow nuclear physicists to understand how strange impurities, like the lambda, can affect the size, shape, and collective motion of nuclei." but this article has been published in 2001, so, as 'Millener' predicted, nuclear physicists understood how strange impurities (or as I asked in the title, if the other quarks besides S U and D have some 'impurities') can affect the nuclei?

There are six flavors of quark. They differ by mass, charge, and flavor-changing probabilities
